# Understanding the following datatype in c++

Tags: c++, vector, bitcoin, deque

Snippet 1:

```
// Byte-vector that clears its contents before deletion
typedef std::vector<char, zero_after_free_allocator<char> > CSerializeData;
```

Snippet 2:

```
std::deque<CSerializeData> vSendMsg;
```

The above example is from bitcoin sources which does complicated typedefs for internal usage.  From the comments, we can simply assume `zero_after_free_allocator` is for cleaning up data.

What is `vSendMsg` exactly? Is it a deque of vector of chars?

**Update:**

Snippet 3:

```
std::deque<CSerializeData>::iterator it = vSendMsg.insert(vSendMsg.end(), CSerializeData());
```

What are we doing here? Looks like we are inserting a class and getting iterator. How will I insert data into this?

Comment: Yes. [[[[[[[[[[[

Comment: well yes what else would it be. If you are not sure you can use `typeinfo` debugging to check.

Comment: Thanks people. I updated the question as well. Kindly see

Comment: Thanks. If possible, convert your comment as your post. I will mark it as the right answer and call this resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How will I insert data into this?

You have an iterator to the newly inserted `vector`, so `it->` affects that `vector`: `it->push_back('x');`.

Until you're confident with these things, you might want to do things one step at a time:

```
CSerializeData& v = *it;
v.push_back('x');
```

That way if the conversion to reference fails you can work out why before worrying whether the `push_back`'s the right way to add data to a `vector`.